# The menu and almost everything disappeared on Blender

Tags: interface, add-on

I am using Blender 3.1 on my Macbook and was trying to install the Screencast Keys addon, which wasn't working. I kept getting an error. So someone recommended that I access the addons folder through the package contents and add the screencast keys folder there. Apparently it had worked for a lot of people, but not for me. Now all my menus are gone when I open blender and I am unable to do anything. How do I fix the issue?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Blender hasn't found some vital file(s) required for startup.

To start with I'd suggest uninstalling the screencast keys add-on from wherever you tried to install it. Just delete all the files you placed there (hopefully just the one file/folder). If that doesn't work, try starting again with a fresh Blender install. If you had a lot of add-ons installed then I realise that this is undesirable but it may be your last resort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At the end, I had to reinstall Blender to get everything working again.